# Can't remove space before title with `titlesec` package

Tags: vspace

I've set all the spacing arguments to 0 but still can't get rid of the space before the chapter title. There's enough top margin already for an a5 size booklet. Here's the mwe:

```latex
\documentclass[openany,a5paper,14pt]{extbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper,inner=0.7in,outer=0.5in}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% {command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before}[after]
\titleformat{\chapter}{\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\LARGE}
% {command}{left}{before}{after}[right]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{14pt}
\title{bestseller}

\author{the greatest author}

\date{coming soon}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
Explicabo excepturi fugiat magnam enim. Itaque itaque nam aut non aut necessitatibus facere voluptate. Et fugiat rem tenetur sed. Aut iure animi culpa optio illum aut.

Odit tempora ea possimus. Quo beatae voluptate fugit optio veritatis quia et. Optio expedita laudantium voluptatum id quisquam.

Voluptas aspernatur assumenda temporibus nulla. Minus sed non totam rem. Voluptatem vero et distinctio voluptate et iusto quasi. Culpa assumenda vel et veniam veritatis dolorem. Autem in magnam dolore. Sed ducimus blanditiis a.

Eaque sapiente quo doloremque dignissimos optio. Sint rem aut voluptatem. Saepe esse mollitia voluptas. Saepe laudantium minima laudantium hic. Est modi iste omnis deserunt tempore.

Ut ullam tenetur eaque rem nostrum asperiores repudiandae. Dolorem quia quos non ut. Error dolor sed enim eius aliquam et impedit.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\chapter{Second}
Explicabo excepturi fugiat magnam enim. Itaque itaque nam aut non aut necessitatibus facere voluptate. Et fugiat rem tenetur sed. Aut iure animi culpa optio illum aut.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is a \vspace* at the begin, so basically a rule, which is placed at a distance of  \topskip and then the chapter title is the second line. So you need some negative value, e.g. `-\baselineskip`  ( you will have to decide which value gives the output you want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that the title is *really* flush with the top margin, use

```
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-28pt}{14pt}
```

(the value has been computed by trial and error).

[image]

The hairline showing the top margin is courtesy of the `showframe` option to `\geometry`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want? I used the `explicit` option of titlesec and a simple `\raisebox` (value found by trial & error).

```
    \documentclass[openany,a5paper,14pt]{extbook}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a5paper,inner=0.7in,outer=0.5in}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    % {command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before}[after]
    \titleformat{\chapter}{\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\raisebox{2.7ex}[0pt][0pt]{\LARGE #1}}
    % {command}{left}{before}{after}[right]
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{14pt}
    \title{bestseller}

    \author{the greatest author}

    \date{coming soon}
    \pagestyle{plain}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{First}
    Explicabo excepturi fugiat magnam enim. Itaque itaque nam aut non aut necessitatibus facere voluptate. Et fugiat rem tenetur sed. Aut iure animi culpa optio illum aut.

    Odit tempora ea possimus. Quo beatae voluptate fugit optio veritatis quia et. Optio expedita laudantium voluptatum id quisquam.

    Voluptas aspernatur assumenda temporibus nulla. Minus sed non totam rem. Voluptatem vero et distinctio voluptate et iusto quasi. Culpa assumenda vel et veniam veritatis dolorem. Autem in magnam dolore. Sed ducimus blanditiis a.

    Eaque sapiente quo doloremque dignissimos optio. Sint rem aut voluptatem. Saepe esse mollitia voluptas. Saepe laudantium minima laudantium hic. Est modi iste omnis deserunt tempore.

    Ut ullam tenetur eaque rem nostrum asperiores repudiandae. Dolorem quia quos non ut. Error dolor sed enim eius aliquam et impedit.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \chapter{Second}
    Explicabo excepturi fugiat magnam enim. Itaque itaque nam aut non aut necessitatibus facere voluptate. Et fugiat rem tenetur sed. Aut iure animi culpa optio illum aut.

    \end{document}
```

[image]